# Yeoman grunt build and grunt serve:dist are broken

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, build, gruntfile

I began a web project using yeoman angular-generator, it works great when I run grunt serve, but after using grunt build and grunt serve:dist my project is broken. The css and images are not showing up and my inspect element shows that $('.foo').masonry() is not a function. I'm very new to angular, yeoman and grunt, and am truly not sure why it is broken in grunt serve:dist but works great with grunt serve, any help would greatly appreciated.

Here is my index.html, the Gruntfile.js is unchanged since generation.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">

    <script src="./scripts/libs/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/libs/greensock/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="yeoboyApp">

    <div id="view-port" class="container-fluid">
      <div ng-view="" autoscroll="true"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/skrollr/src/skrollr.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-skrollr/dist/angular-skrollr.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
        <script src="./scripts/libs/skrollr.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./scripts/libs/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/project.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/exposurements.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/google.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/htc.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/portbound.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/massive.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/churn.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/tessalate.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/tempsense.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/website.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any other info I should provide?